# What is the equivalent of Java's List in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, list

I wonder if Objective-C offers support for `Lists`? Or .. is `NSMutableArray` a way to go, instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes `NSMutableArray` ([Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) would in most cases be the appropriate class for lists (with `NSArray` being the immutable counterpart).

Contrary to Java's collection classes **Objective-C**'s (or rather **Foundation**'s) arrays are opaque class clusters that completely hide their implementation.

Edit:  ***snip*** <sup>(see comment by **orange80**)</sup>

While Java has a ton of collection classes such as:

- `HashSet`
- `TreeSet`
- `LinkedHashSet`
- `ArrayList`
- `LinkedList`
- `PriorityQueue`
- `HashMap`
- `TreeMap`
- `LinkedHashMap`
- `WeakHashMap`
- `IdentityHashMap`
- `CopyOnWriteArrayList`
- `CopyOnWriteArraySet`
- `EnumSet`
- `EnumMap`
- `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`
- `LinkedBlockingQueue`
- `ArrayBlockingQueue`
- `PriorityBlockingQueue`
- `DelayQueue`
- `SynchronousQueue`
- `ConcurrentHashMap`

Objective-C however (again, actually the **Foundation** SDK) only provides a very limited number of collection classes:

- `CFMutableDictionary`
- `CFMutableBag`
- `CFMutableBitVector`
- `CFMutableSet`
- `CFMutableArray`
- `CFBinaryHeap`
- `CFMutableTree`

or preferably their NS-equivalents:

- `NSMutableDictionary`
- `NSDictionary`
- `NSMutableSet`
- `NSSet`
- `NSCountedSet`
- `NSMutableArray`
- `NSArray`

For a full insight in the matter I recommend this read:
http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html (the author is a member of Apple's Foundation Team)

Comment: You can tell if you do this: BOOL isMutable = [someArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]];   so it's not 100% true to say you can't tell the difference.  It's just that they both match the NSArray interface.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you'll want to use `NSMutableArray` for equivalent behaviour (though the implementation is very different.) You also have the option of using `CFMutableArray` (a C-based API that is a little more flexible than `NSMutableArray` and is toll-free bridged with it.) If you're using C++ rather than (or in addition to) Objective-C, you have any of the STL collection types (such as `std::list<T>`, `std::vector<T>`, etc.) whose suitability will depend on your exact use case.